# Mortarboard / Epic / Legendary badges threshold too high?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was looking through badges, and I've noticed that those three actually have a really high threshold to be reached in order to be awarded (compared to the difficulty of the task itself), proven by the fact that only 391 users have been awarded `Mortarboard`, only 5 have been awarded `Epic` and **none** has ever been awared `Legendary`. Perhaps an escalation along the lines of `Popular Question` / `Notable Question` / `Famous Question` like 1 (`Mortarboard`) - 25 (`Epic`) - 100 (`Legenday`) would fit better?

---

Leaderboard [here!](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/160805/legendary-badge-advancement-topcount)

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't think they are too high. Each SE site has its own voting culture, and it's been noted time and again that we don't vote much - we vote less than, for example, Unix & Linux. We have only two 100k users, U&L have two of those and one 200k user. They also have awarded the Legendary badge [thrice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary). Yet we best them on all but one of the [traffic stats](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic). We are just a tough community.

Answer (score 4):

The Legendary badge is there to be hard to get. Epic was not that hard to get :)

"and none has ever been awared Legendary"

One of us soon will reach it. I am not that one by the way since I am on 76/150 (in case anyone wonders how to find out: see https://askubuntu.com/reputation at the bottom).

Quality over quantity :D

Comment: @%#%#£@ I'm only on 30.

Comment: Well, 2 here (!), anyway I agree that the legendary badge should be very hard to get, I was just surprised that with the high number of really fine posts posted by the top users *none* of them could be able to get it yet. I posted a Data.SE query to check the Ask Ubuntu leaderboard for this badge if someone wants to check it out

Answer (score 1):

And I'm the only one with a [Reversal badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/55/reversal) though it'll take me another 10 years for a Legendary badge...  :-(

Comment: Yeah, that one's also tough to get. Upvoted that answer further tough!